# Preventing Caching of swf files in Adobe AIR

Tags: air

I'm trying to prevent caching of swf files in Adobe AIR application.

The situation is like this, I've my AIR application running and i'm dragging and dropping swf files from external (flex builder) onto AIR application. The swf files are loading. But if i recompile the swf files with some changes and drop the swf file onto already running AIR app, the changes are not reflected instead if i restart the application, the changes are reflected. Here the swf files are loading from the cache and i want to prevent this from happening.

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this.

Thanks,
Swaraj.

Answer (score 0):

Add an unique string to avoid caching:

```
 file.swf?nocache=" + new Date().getTime());
```